# How to use angularjs factory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
   var myappWebApp = angular.module('myappWebApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

//factory

```
myappWebApp.factory('wired', function () {

    this.currOp = false;

    return {
        currOp1 : this.currOp
    }
});

   // controller

myappWebApp.controller('wiredCtrl',
    function ($scope, $http, wired) {

        //data
        $scope.currOp = wired.currOp;//why is this undefined?
        $scope.currOpInText = wired.currOpInText();
        $scope.altOpInText = null;
        $scope.boxA = null;
....
```

How should my scope.currOp always automatically have the same value as wired.currOp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are copying just a bool, you can't.  Booleans are copied by value, so you don't get reference-based updates.

You might consider using an object with a boolean:

```
myappWebApp.factory('wired', function () {

    this.state = { curOp: false };

    return {
        state: this.state
    }
});
```

Then, when you reference it in your scope, you can do this:

```
myappWebApp.controller('wiredCtrl',
    function ($scope, $http, wired) {

    $scope.opState = wired.state;
});
```

And now when `curOp` changes, the controller will have the change.  You can watch for changes:

```
$scope.$watch("opState.curOp", function(newVal, oldVal) {
    // Handle changes in curOp
});
```

Or you can bind to it:

```
CurOp: {{state.currOp}}
```

**Note:** You asked: "why is this undefined?"  The answer is because your service is exposing `currOp1` but you are referencing `currOp`